# How to store random bytes in a file using character encoding?

Tags: python, random, encoding

I'm trying to run someone else's Python 2 program on Python 3 (with Windows 7).  Its purpose is to generate large factorials then use them as a stream of random numbers.  The program converts a decimal factorial to byte values from 0 to 255 and writes `chr(byte value)` to a file.  It computes each byte by moving through the factorial in sections of 8 decimals.  However, encoding changed from Python 2 to 3 (I'm not certain as to exactly what or why it matters), and the `chr()` command won't work for any values from 128 to 159 (but values 160 to 255 work)- the program raises  "`UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '(the character point)' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>`"

I have tried changing the file encoding with "`open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8")`", and this successfully writes all the bytes.  However, when I test the file's randomness properties they are significantly worse than results the author got.

**What should I change to store the character bytes without affecting the randomness of the data?**

The test program is called "ent."  From the command prompt, it takes a file as an argument and then outputs a few randomness statistics.  For more information, visit http://www.fourmilab.ch/random/ , its website.

- My ent results for file from !500,000, using `open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8")`:

  ```
  Entropy = 6.251272 bits per byte.

  Optimum compression would reduce the size of this 471812 byte file by 21 percent.

  Chi square distribution for 471812 samples is 6545600.65, and randomly
  would exceed this value less than 0.01 percent of the times.

  Arithmetic mean value of data bytes is 138.9331 (127.5 = random).
  Monte Carlo value for Pi is 3.173294335 (error 1.01 percent).
  Serial correlation coefficient is 0.162915 (totally uncorrelated = 0.0).
  ```
- The authors' ent results for a file from !500,000:

  ```
  Entropy = 7.999373 bits per byte.

  Optimum compression would reduce the size of this 313417 byte file by 0 percent.

  Chi square distribution for 31347 samples is 272.63, and randomly would
  exceed this value 25.00 percent of the times.

  Arithmetic mean value of data bytes is 127.6336 (127.5 = random).
  Monte Carlo value for Pi is 3.149475458 (error 0.25 percent).
  Serial correlation coefficient is -0.001209 (totally uncorrelated = 0.0).
  ```

Comment: To write a binary file you should open it in binary mode `open(filename, "wb")` and write byte-like objects to it. For example to write a byte with the value of 123: `file.write(bytes([123]))`.

Comment: In Python2 world "a byte" and "a character" are interchangeable; in Python3/Unicode world there are thousands of characters in the world so they need more than one byte each to store (and the idea of "a character" is fuzzy too). There is now another layer in the middle: text is a sequence of Unicode codepoints "ABé" -> there's a choice of encodings how to serialize those to and from byte values -> a block of opaque serialized data bytes. Byte value for "A" depends on which serializer you choose (utf8), and encodings add patterns to the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like timakro had the answer (thanks):

"To write a binary file you should open it in binary mode open(filename, "wb") and write byte-like objects to it. For example to write a byte with the value of 123: file.write(bytes([123]))." -timakro

When I write "`bytes([byte value from 0-255])`" to the file, it gets the randomness scores expected with the ent program.  So, I change Python 2's `chr()` to `bytes()` for the program to store bytes in Python 3.  No character encoding is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example (in Python 3):

```
# check if the characters are matching Unicode
l1 = [chr(i) for i in range(128, 160)]
print("{}\n".format(l1))

s1 = " ".join(l1)

# display these characters for visual comparison
# before writing them to file
print("INITIAL:")
print(s1)

pf = open("somefile", "wb")
pf.write(s1.encode("utf-8"))
pf.close()

po = open("somefile", "rb")
out = po.read()
po.close()

s2 = out.decode('utf-8')

# display these characters for visual comparison    
# after writing them to file and reading them from it
print("AFTER:")
print(s2)
```

In which we test two theories:

- can the characters (128 to 159) be encoded
- can we write all the data as binary into a file?

In the first demonstration, we can clearly see that data does match in the Unicode Character Map.

As for the second theory goes, we can obviously write and retrieve binary data in the original form as the output suggests:

[image: output]

Comment: This method is equivalent to the command I mentioned- "open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8")"- even in "wb".  The problem is that this changes the randomness of the data as measured by the ent program.